# System differential equations operational method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am trying  to solve this system of differential equation
$$x''-2y'+x=0$$
$$y''-2x'+y=e^{2t}$$
Then

$$D^2 x-2Dy+x=0$$
$$D^2 y-2Dx+y=e^{2t}$$

But I don't know what to do next

$$(D^2 +1)x-2Dy=0$$
$$(D^2 +1)y-2Dx=e^{2t}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x(D^2 +1)-2Dy=0$$
$$y(D^2 +1)-2Dx=e^{2t}$$
Differentiate:
$$2D(D^2 +1)x-4D^2y=0$$
$$(D^2 +1)^2y-2D(D^2+1)x=(D^2+1)e^{2t}$$
Now sum both DE and solve.
$$(D^2 +1)^2y-4D^2y=(D^2+1)e^{2t}$$
More simply:
$$(D^2 -1)^2y=(D^2+1)e^{2t}$$
$$(D^2 -1)^2y=5e^{2t}$$